# SPFx - Upgrade - New site columns got not attached to site content type

Tags: spfx-webparts, feature-upgrade

I am deploying two new site column and try to attach them to a existing site content type with

```
<ApplyElementManifests>
  <ElementManifest Location="5b1d5abd-297f-41e2-88d4-3c2fc9c23962\elements-v2.xml" />
</ApplyElementManifests>
<AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="0x0100964BEED5C19240C5A561F41A2C0A6A20" FieldId="{7900be76-ca1a-4563-9b4c-f738805a401b}" PushDown="TRUE" />
<AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="0x0100964BEED5C19240C5A561F41A2C0A6A20" FieldId="{3630d838-1a0d-4fcf-99d6-6d7636356d22}" PushDown="TRUE" />
```

The site columns will be deployed, but both fields will not be attached to the content type.
Version number of the Solution and the Feature are the same:

```
"version": "1.1.0.0",
    "assets": {
      "elementManifests": [
        "elements.xml",
        "elements-v2.xml"
      ],
      "elementFiles":[
        "xxx.xml",
        "yyy.xml",
        "zzz.xml",
        "Documentation.docx"         
      ],
      "upgradeActions": [
        "upgrade-actions.xml"
      ]   
    }
```

The elements-v2.xml does contain the definition of my two new columns.
If I now add this Package to a fresh Site, the new columns are deployed, but not attached to the site content type, nor pushing down to the list content type.
All definitions and Guids have been verified. I can attach the columns by UI without any error.
I always follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package#define-upgrade-actions-for-new-version) approach, but this time, I don't see what might be wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm the GUID of the feature you included in the **package-solution.json**  file? Does it match the value `5b1d5abd-297f-41e2-88d4-3c2fc9c23962`?

Comment: Yes, checked that, otherwise the new fields could not be deployed.

Comment: Have you placed your `AddContentTypeField` within the `UpgradeActions` section? You can refer to the following link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/upgradeactions-element-feature

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.
You need to add the new field also to the content type definition from the origin elements.xml, then the field will get attached to the content type when adding the update through UI.